# Matplotlib install hanging on raspberry pi zero w

Tags: linux, installation, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

so I followed [this Tutorial](http://www.knight-of-pi.org/installing-python3-6-on-a-raspberry-pi/)
and installed python 3.6.3 onto my raspberry pi zero w.
It is running Raspbian Stretch 4.14, I'm having this issue with both the desktop and lite version.

Everything works fine, I then go to install matplotlib using `sudo pip3 install matplotlib`

and it collects it.
downloads it, but reaches 100% and nothing, it just hangs.

I've used -vvv to see what's going on and A LOT is happening but it's too fast for me to read, then all of a sudden it just stops and no more text.
I need to use ^c to get back to the command line.

This works: `sudo pip install pip-install-test`

What I've tried:
Changing pip version,
fresh reinstall,
installing different version of matplotlib (3.0.3 instead of 3.1.0),
this method : `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`

any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: When you use verbose option is there any error in last ~10-15 lines?

Comment: @Biswapriyo
This is what was showing, most of it was pretty much this:
https://pasteboard.co/IhFoQfA.jpg